# How do I remove the 2 lowest values in a ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I started with the array:

```
np.random.seed(959)
superArray = np.random.randint(101, size=(5,3))
```

I need to calculate the median of `superArray` after removing the 2 smallest values.

I can't seem to locate any methods for deleting values that work with ndarrays. The code below is what I thought it could be.

```
np.median(superArray.delete(superArray,[min(superArray),min(superArray)]))
```

Of course that spat out an error at me because `delete` isn't a method for the ndarray type but this is what I was going for.

Comment: please define `remove`

Comment: With a 2d array, removing 2 values is impossible.  Give a concrete example, for example, even as simple as  `np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to delete or remove anything. You can just work on a view of the array that doesn't include the elements you don't want. The easiest way to do that is with slicing. So you could put them in order, and skip the first two, for example

```
np.median(np.sort(superArray.ravel())[2:])
```

You need the `ravel()` to flatten the array.

Answer (score 1):

you can `np.partition` and `ravel`.  `np.partition` will be faster than whole sort in large arrays

```py
np.random.seed(959)
superArray = np.random.randint(101, size=(5,3))
np.partition(superArray.ravel(), 2)[2:]
```

Comment: Smart. I have never used that function. I guess you just need to apply `median` to that result and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing `superArray` you can use `np.quantile`. `np.median(x)` is the same as `np.quantile(x,1/2)`. If you leave the two smallest elements out you are shifting the mid point up by 1, i.e. you can use `np.quantile(superArray,1/2+1/(superArray.size-1)`

```
# compute reference value for validation
ref = np.median(np.partition(superArray.ravel(),2)[2:])

# quantile method
np.quantile(superArray,1/2+1/(superArray.size-1)) == ref
# True
```

`np.quantile` and `np.median` are both a bit slow, you can get better performance by using `np.partition` instead:

```
# do-it-yourself quantile
idx = np.arange((superArray.size+1)//2,(superArray.size+2)//2+1)    
np.partition(superArray,idx,axis=None)[idx].mean() == ref
#True
```

Timings:

```
def f():
    idx = np.arange((superArray.size+1)//2,(superArray.size+2)//2+1)
    return np.partition(superArray,idx,axis=None)[idx].mean()

def g():
    return np.quantile(superArray,1/2+1/(superArray.size-1))

def h():
    return np.median(np.partition(superArray.ravel(),2)[2:])

def i():
    return np.median(np.sort(superArray.ravel())[2:])

for tag,fn in [('partition',f),('quantile',g),('median+part',h),('median+sort',i)]:
    print(f'{tag:20s} {timeit(fn,number=100000)*10:.4f} us')

# partition            14.5955 us
# quantile             96.5980 us
# median+part          30.1133 us
# median+sort          29.4419 us
```

Same for larger (1000x1000) `superArray`:

```
partition            12.2952 ms
quantile             12.7227 ms
median+part          20.8914 ms
median+sort          87.3877 ms
```

Comment: I hope this gets accepted, I never would have thought of this!